# Pagination of buttons on screen - Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement scrollable list of buttons.

[image: SS]

As shown in screenshot above, there is 3 buttons shown on the screen. I am trying create a list of buttons, that user can scroll them 3 at a time.

I tried 2 ways:

**1- View Pager:** I created 1 fragment for each 3 buttons.

The scroll works perfectly as I wanted, but when i need to add new button, it is a real overhead work.

**2- RecyclerView:** Which is works well but doesnt scroll 3 at a time.

So i want to show on screen only 3 items. When user scroll, it will scroll to the next 3 items.

Is it possible to do this with RecyclerView (which is easier to add to it)?

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be using an adapter which shows 3 elements per item, then use the [PageSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper.html) to get the paging effect:

The Adapter:

```
  public class ButtonsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ButtonsRecyclerAdapter.ButtonsViewHolder> {

    private List<Button> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public ButtonsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_buttons, null);
        return new ButtonsViewHolder(layoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ButtonsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int startPosition = getItemCount() * position;
        int endPosition = startPosition + 3;

        for (int i = startPosition; i < endPosition || i < mButtons.size(); i++) {
            Button neededButton = holder.getButton(i - position);
            neededButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Do whant you want to do with it
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return null != mButtons ? ((int) Math.ceil((double) mButtons.size() / 3)) : 0;
    }

    public class ButtonsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Button mButtonFirst;
        Button mButtonSecond;
        Button mButtonThird;

        public ButtonsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mButtonFirst = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_first);
            mButtonSecond = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_second);
            mButtonThird = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_third);
        }

        Button getButton(int index) {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    return mButtonFirst;
                case 1:
                    return mButtonSecond;
                case 2:
                    return mButtonThird;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The list item layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_third"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it possible to have the viewholder holding only 1 button ?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do it with this approach

Comment: alright, Thank you so much for this solution, i am applying it now, i will inform when i finish

Comment: It did not work, the buttons gets repeated, i could not fix it :(